# How many straight lines are included in each hypersurface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

In $R^5$ we further consider the constant level set algebraic hypersurfaces of the multi lener polynomial

$$c =x_1x_4 + x_2x_5 + x_2x_3x_4 - x_1x_2x_3x_4
- x_1x_2x_4x_5 - x_2x_3x_4x_5 + x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5.$$

How many straight lines are included in each  hypersurface ?

As an example, the constant level set zero hypersurface contains the linear varieties $Ox_3x_4x_5 :x_1 = 0;x_2 = 0; Ox_1x_3x_5 : x_2 = 0;x_4 = 0; Ox_2x_3 : x_1 = 0;x_4 = 0;x_5 = 0$. Indeed, we
have

$$c =x_1(x_4 - x_2x_3x_4 - x_2x_4x_5 + x_2x_3x_4x_5)+ x_2(x_5 + x_3x_4- x_3x_4x_5)  .$$

Can anyone help me to study this case ?

Mentioning some sources or lecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $c = 0$, the $3$-plane given by $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 0$ is contained in your surface. So if $c = 0$ you have infinitely many lines contained in the hypersurface.

Similarly, for $ c \neq 0$, again the $2$-plane $x_2 = 0, x_1 = 1, x_4 = c$ is contained in your hypersurface, so again it contains infinitely many lines.

In general, determine how many lines an hypersurface contains can be tricky, for example a cubic surface in $\mathbb P^3$ contains $27$ lines (I am working with complex coefficients) but it's not easy to prove.

Comment: Can you tell me some references on this subject

Comment: A pretty advanced reference which I really like is _3264 and all that, a second course in algebraic geometry_ by Harris and Eisenbud which is explaining the basics of enumerative geometry and intersection theory. 
The keyword here is enumerative geometry. Also, the variety of line is called the Fano variety, so googling this will give you lot of informations. But this is a pretty complicate subject and you need to have a good background in algebraic geometry. Good luck !

Comment: Why do we assume that $x_1=0,x_2=0$ has an interpretation?
  Or I can take any variable.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. The points such that $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 0$ have an geometric interpretation as they are given by a $3$-dimensional linear subspace of $R^3$. In general, if you have a linear equation, for example $x_1 - x_3 + 3x_4 = 0$, this will give you an hyperplane. Several equations will give you intersection of hyperplanes, and if the equations are linearly independant, $k$ linear equations in $R^n$ will give you a $n-k$ linear subspace.